# EmberJS: Loading model from another (non-nested) controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a Message model which is set up as follows:

```
App.Message = DS.Model.extend({
    subject   : DS.attr( 'string' ),
    message   : DS.attr( 'string' ),
    deletedBy : DS.attr(),
    createdAt : DS.attr( 'string' ),

    sender     : DS.belongsTo( 'user', {embedded : false, key : 'sender'} ),
    recipient  : DS.belongsTo( 'user', {embedded : false, key : 'recipient'} )
});
```

In my InboxController, I have set up a dependency with the UsersController. However, when I load the inbox route directly, it is not loading the UsersController model (it's not nested). What is the most appropriate way to get this to work?

InboxController:

```
App.InboxController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: ['users'],
    itemController: 'inboxItem',
    ...
});
```

**Update**

Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9asHJ/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need one controller into another, you can use the `needs` and get access to the `UsersController` via `this.get('controllers.users.something')`

[Docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/)

[Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/LS46m/1/)

Incase, you need some controller or model to be injected to all controllers or routes or something, you can perform dependency injection during app initialization.

[Refer docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#toc_initializers)

Comment: In your example, the isAdmin attribute is being set by the controller. However, in my setup the model is set up by the router. I created a fiddle and added it to the question. Is injecting the model into all controllers the only solution for this problem? Thanks!

Comment: A `route#model` hook will get called only when you visit that route.

Comment: One thing i can suggest you is that you fetch that model from the `applicationRoute`. It's the only route that gets invoked whereever your app boots.
http://jsfiddle.net/selvaG/9asHJ/4/